# How to get Tesseract working with CGO on Windows?

Tags: c++, go, tesseract, cgo, goland

I've been trying to get [otiai10/gosseract](https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract) (Go package for Tesseract C++ library) working on Windows without success. As a requirement, [gosseract requires the installation](https://github.com/otiai10/gosseract#install) of *"[tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc), including library and headers"*.

The [Tesseract Windows compiling documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/Compiling.md#windows) mentions the usage of [SW](https://software-network.org/) and [Vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/README.md), which to my understanding relies on MSVC and is hence [not compatible with Go](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20982).

The documentation also [mentions the existence of Cygwin packages](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/Compiling.md#cygwin). I have tried leveraging them by installing `tesseract-ocr` (`5.2.0-1`), `tesseract-ocr-devel` (`5.2.0-1`), `tesseract-ocr-eng` (`5.00-1`) as well as `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` and `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-core` after which I defined the following environment variables:

```
CGO_CFLAGS=-IC:\cygwin64\usr\include
CGO_CPPFLAGS=-IC:\cygwin64\usr\include
CGO_LDFLAGS=-LC:\cygwin64\lib
PATH=C:\cygwin64\bin;...
CC=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
CXX=C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
```

However, trying to compile (through [GoLand](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/)) an example project ([otiai10/ocrserver](https://github.com/otiai10/ocrserver)) still results in linker errors:

```
GOROOT=C:\Users\REDACTED\go\go1.18rc1 #gosetup
GOPATH=C:\Users\REDACTED\go #gosetup
C:\Users\REDACTED\go\go1.18rc1\bin\go.exe build -o C:\Users\REDACTED\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand\___go_build_github_com_otiai10_ocrserver.exe github.com/otiai10/ocrserver #gosetup
# github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: $WORK\b133\_x003.o: in function `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*)':
/cygdrive/c/Users/REDACTED/go/pkg/mod/github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2@v2.3.1/C:/cygwin64/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:215: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, bool)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/REDACTED/go/pkg/mod/github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2@v2.3.1/C:/cygwin64/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:215: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, bool)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/REDACTED/go/pkg/mod/github.com/otiai10/gosseract/v2@v2.3.1/C:/cygwin64/usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:215: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Init(char const*, char const*, tesseract::OcrEngineMode, char**, int, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const*, bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**How can one get *"[tesseract-ocr](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc), including library and headers"* properly set up on a Windows machine for CGO compatibility?**

---

```
> go version
go version go1.17 windows/amd64
> C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 11.3.0
> C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 11.3.0
> C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld.exe --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.38
```

Comment: I got progress, as in figuring out some include errors, that was by using vcpkg and setting environment variables for the include folders as CPATH.